# Setting up access to one table

Tags: sql-server

I just set up access for a SQL server user to a single table.
I did this by putting giving the user the db_datareader role.
Then I set the permissions for all the tables I didn't want this user to access by setting all the checkboxes in the DENY column for each table.

That worked but was a lot of box clicking.

Is there a shorter, easier way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

YES!  You've done it exactly backwards.  Remove the user from the datareader role (which as you've discovered grants select to the entire database) and only grant select access to that one table.

```
USE MyDB
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.MyTable to JoeUser
```

Or, in SQL Server Management Studio

1. Right-click the table and get properties
2. Click Permissions in the menu on the left
3. Click Search and find your user
4. Put a check in the Grant column in the row that says Select

Comment: That is how I did in the first try. Then I logged in with that user account and I didn't see any table. Hence the backward attempt.

Comment: @Eric Did you add the login to the database?

Comment: Yes, every database for which I want to use this login, I set the mapping.